# How to assign console output to a string in matlab?

Tags: matlab

In matlab, evaluating a variable without a semicolon causes it to be printed on the console output. `disp` is similar but does not include the variable name. Is there a way to get either console output as a string?

e.g.

```
>> x = [-1; 2];
>> x

x =

    -1
     2
```

Is there a way to get this output assigned to a variable in a string, i.e. in this example the string `"x = \n\n -1\n  2\n"`

Comment: Why just out of curiosity

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good point, I cannot think of any good reason that you want to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x=[1;2]
s=evalc('x')
```

Then `s='\nx =\n\n     0\n     1'`